# how to link my app to any text in windows?

Tags: java

I've just learned Java SE basics and want to make a utility program that popups a small window when selecting a text and when click the small window the selected text is converted to another equivalent characters in other language.

I wrote a class that should take any selected text from windows and convert it to the targeted language, how can I  configure my app to windows backend to allow my program take the text as parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't -- not with core Java, since the key functionality that you're looking for, for the program to be able to listen to user interaction with other programs and the OS, is something that Java was not built to do. One of Java's prime directives from the very beginning was to be able to run on multiple platforms, and in order to achieve this, the creators made the language and its tools as OS agnostic as possible, and so tasks that require a close integration with the OS don't work well with Java.

I'd suggest using JNA or JNI which would allow your Java program to make OS calls including mouse and keyboard hooks, or integrating another tool such as an OS scripting tool into your Java program via processes/streams.

Comment: Aha thanks a lot, it's my first time to hear about JNA i will learn it. Thanks again.